# Computing logits for a vector and for all vectors in a set

Tags: python, numpy

I've had to write two different functions (shown below), but I want to combine the two functions into one. Is there a way to do this?

`softmax_a_set()` takes a list of numpy arrays, applies `softmax()` to each individual numpy array, and then returns a list of processed numpy arrays.

```
def softmax(a_vector):
    """Compute a logit for a vector."""
    denom = sum(numpy.exp(a_vector))
    logit = numpy.exp(a_vector)/denom
    return logit

def softmax_a_set(a_set):
    """computes logits for all vectors in a set"""
    softmax_set = numpy.zeros(a_set.shape)    

    for x in range(0, len(a_set)):
        softmax_set[x] = softmax(a_set[x])

    return softmax_set
```

Comment: Ah, I see.  Emphasis on *didn't*.  Defining a function is just a shortcut anyway.  First, you define `a_vector` as whatever is passed in, in this case `a_set[x]`.  Next, you define `denom`.  Next, you define `logit`.  Next, you use `logit` elsewhere, in this case `softmax_set[x] = logit`.

Comment: Why do you have/want to pack them into a single function? Following the [Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/), your solution looks perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you want to combine them into two functions? It’s possible, but I don’t think it would be an improvement. They’re two fairly distinct functions, and cramming the code for both into a single function would make the code less readable.

If you really need a single function that handles both, you could do something like:

```
def softmax(a):
    if isinstance(a, vector):
        return softmax_a_vector(a)
    elif isinstance(a, set):
        return softmax_a_set(a)
```

which gets what you want, but you keep the nice separation of code into distinct functions.

---

One other minor thing: you can improve the for loop in `softmax_a_set` with enumerate:

```
for idx, a_vector in enumerate(a_set):
    softmax_set[idx] = softmax(a_vector)
```